# Vim autocmd pattern that matches only files in a particular directory (not in subdirectories)

Tags: vim

I am trying to match all and only files that are directly on my Desktop.  But the autocmd pattern `*/Desktop/*` also matches files in any subdirectory of the Desktop.  What pattern can do what I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use a suitable regex, but this one might fail if you have `/`s in the filename, but you can improve it:

```
au BufRead * if expand('<amatch>') =~ "/Desktop/[^/]*$" | set tw=90 | endif
```

Another way is to use two commands, one reverting the other:

```
  au BufRead */Desktop/*  set tw=90
  au BufRead */Desktop/*/*  set tw=31
```

Comment: You should use `expand('<amatch>')` in place of `expand('%')` in first case. Otherwise it is not guaranteed that there is at least one slash (with `<amatch>` `/` is always used as a path separator, with `%` it uses system path separator which may be `\ ` or `:`). It also makes sense to duplicate pattern (matching against `*/Desktop/*` in `:au` arguments is much faster then executing `:au` code; though almost always you won’t notice the difference).

Comment: Nice, it works.  I'm very surprised there is not a simple way to do this with an autocmd pattern though.  Seems like a fairly common use case.